# mongodb schema.createIndex is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am trying to create an index in my messageSchema

```
    var messageSchema = new Schema({
    senderName : String,
    content : String,
    reply : String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    room : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }
});
```

// this is how to tried to create the index

```
 messageSchema.createIndex({content : "text"}, function(err, data){
     console.log(err);
     console.log(data);
    });
```

//Also tried

```
  messageSchema.createIndex({content : "text"});
```

//tried this too

```
 messageSchema.createIndex({"content" : "text"});
```

The error I keep on getting is

> `TypeError: messageSchema.createIndex is not a function`

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you are using mongoose. Under the hood,

> Each schema maps to a MongoDB collection and defines the shape of the documents within that collection.

In the mongo shell, `collection.createIndex()` works, but in mongoose you need to use `mySchema.index()`. Mongoose will do the work.

See here for more information: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html.

Answer (score 4):

from mongoose:

```
var messageSchema = new Schema({
    senderName : String,
    content : { type: String, index: true },
    reply : String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    room : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }
});
 messageSchema.index({content: 'text'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is called [index](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index), not `createIndex`