# Mongoose indexing sub-array compoent

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing

I'm trying to indexing one of my subarray component.
My mongoose schema is like that :

```
 mongoose.Schema({
      id: {
        type: String,
        default: uuidv4,
      },
     organization: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
     names: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      language: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: languages,
      },
    },
  ],
    }
```

And If i create the index for organization like that :

```
schema.index({ organization: 'text' })
```

But what I want is to index the name inside the names array so I tried:

```
schema.index({ 'names.name': 'text' })
```

And here the index is not created, do you have an idea why ?

Comment: You can create a _text_ index on the `names.name` field - there are no issues with that. Note that you can have _only one text index per collection_.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that when I try to create it like this: schema.index({ 'names.name': 'text' }) it's not working, no index are add to my schema and I can't figured out why. I have check on mongocompass and I don't have any other text index there

Comment: You can also create the index from Compass or the `mongo` shell. Maybe you need to restart the program to create the index (I am not familiar with the details of creating indexes within Mongoose). Generally, it it convention to create indexes (and other admin tasks) from an administrative tool like `mongo` shell. Also see this SO post on creating index with Mongoose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131316/mongodb-schema-createindex-is-not-a-function

Comment: Unfortunately text index cannot be created from mongocompass... But I ill maybe try from mongo shell, thanks !